# Django - Overriding model's delete() method in base class - recursive problem

Tags: django, django-models

I have a abstract class which has some common methods for all of my models. I have inherited this class in all my models. Now there is a requirement to send the mail whenever a model is deleted. So I have override the delete() method in my abstract class. This leads to the recursive call of same method because calling the super method.

```
    super(Model, self).save(*args, **kwargs) 

    class Common(models.Model): 
             #mail logic
             super(type(self), self).delete(*args, **kwargs)        

    class Child(Common)      
             # fields
```

Comment: It is better to use django signals: `post_delete` or `pre_delete`. For example: lets say your `Child` class has: `Child.parent = ForeignKey(Parent)`. Now if you delete parent: `parent.delete()`, you child will be deleted too (Cascade on delete behaviour). When this happens `delete()` method won't be called on Child object and your `#mail logic` won't be executed. If you would use signals instead, everything works as expected. Read how to use them: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is why you must always use the proper type instead of `type(self)`.

```
super(Common, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: You are correct. But, Since this method is in the common base class to avoid duplicate code. So, we won't know the  Model type. Is there any other option available?

Comment: You don't need the model type, you need the current class. The current class is `Common`.

Comment: Perfect. It works. Thanks a lot. I am just amazed with your speed of response.